# HTML closing tag un-indents by 1 level. Newline in between tags is on same level as tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have looked around for a while now and find a bunch of references both here and elsewhere to settings that have had no effect on this behaviour.

The following are all set, I've played with all of these options to no avail.

```json
{
  "html.autoClosingTags": true,
  "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
  "html.format.preserveNewLines": true,
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",
  "editor.autoIndent": "full",
  "editor.detectIndentation": true
}
```

When taking the following code (Cursor represented by `|`)

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >|</div>
</div>
```

Pressing enter yields

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >
|</div>
</div>
```

While I would like it to yield:

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >
  |</div>
</div>
```

Similarly when taking the following:

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >|
  </div>
</div>
```

Pressing Enter yields an un-indented line:

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >
  |
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of indenting inside the tag:

```html
<div>
  <div
    class="..."
    style="..."
    some-attributes="..."
  >
    |
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

- Moved the Settings I have set to the top of the question since they were missed by a responder.

Comment: Note: If you want to get some extra eyes on this, you can [create an issue ticket for it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose). If you do, please [edit] your question post to link to it. This sounds to me like something worth a feature-request issue ticket.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you are experiencing is due to the default settings of the VS Code HTML formatter. However, there is a setting you can adjust to achieve the desired behavior.

Please provide the path where you changed your settings:

> {
> "html.autoClosingTags": true,
> "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
> "html.format.preserveNewLines": true,
> "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",
> "editor.autoIndent": "full",
> "editor.detectIndentation": true
> }

Add the following setting to your VS Code `settings.json` file:

```
"html.format.indentInnerHtml": true
```

The `settings.json` file can be found by following these steps:

1. Open VScode
2. `Ctrl + shift + p` -> will open command palette
3. Open `Preferences: Open Default Settings(JSON)`
4. Go to line 2300
5. Change false to true
6. Done
   Have a good day, hope this helps!

Comment: That setting is already set to true, see the settings at the bottom of the original question.